# How do I learn new abilities?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How do I leave the new abilities I've got? It says to see the trainer - where can I find them?

[image: World of Warcraft Spellbook]

Comment: Voting to close this obsolete question as "too localized".  It is no longer possible for characters to have untrained skills, as skills are learned automatically (as of patch 5.0.4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find your class trainer. Since you are a Warrior, the following list of warrior trainers should be what you are looking for.

[Warrior Trainers](http://www.wowwiki.com/Warrior_trainers)

And since you are likely to have your heartstone in Stormwind at your level, you should check the [Stormwind Warrior trainer](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=5480).

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to find people in a major city is to ask a guard - they know where everyone is.